# Taylor Theorem with integral remainder for multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a star-shaped (w.r.t the zero) open set. Then we have for a $C^{\infty}$-function $f\colon U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the following formula $$f(x)-f(0)=\sum_{i}x^i\int_{0}^1\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(tx)dt$$. How I can prove, by using this formula, that 
$$f(x)-f(0)=\sum_{i}x^i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(0)+
\sum_{i,j}x^ix^j\int_{0}^1(1-t)\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}(tx)dt$$?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia entry?

Comment: Honestly I didn't.

Comment: Well, I don't know that Wikipedia would have anything useful on "Tylor's Theorem."

Comment: Math.stackexchange doesn't try to avoid duplication with Wikipedia anyway. Math.stackexchange does try to avoid duplication with itself, but I don't know that this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an integration by part (in fact a standard way to prove Taylor's theorem). Use for suitable $u$: $$\int_0^1  1 \cdot u(t) dt = \left[ (t-1) u(t) \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 (t-1) u'(t) \; dt $$